# Get all day events from calendar

Tags: android, calendar

I'm seeing a strange behavior of all day events in the calendar. Accordinng to the docs, their start time should be in UTC millis. However it seems they are shifted with the timezone.

```
    projection = new String[]{CalendarContract.Instances.ORGANIZER, CalendarContract.Instances.TITLE,
            CalendarContract.Instances.DESCRIPTION, CalendarContract.Instances.BEGIN, CalendarContract
            .Instances.END, CalendarContract.Instances.EVENT_LOCATION, CalendarContract.Instances
            .EVENT_TIMEZONE, CalendarContract.Instances.EVENT_END_TIMEZONE, CalendarContract.Instances
            .EVENT_ID, CalendarContract.Instances.ALL_DAY};
dtstart = Long.valueOf(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Instances.BEGIN)));
Date d = new Date(dtstart);
```

If I create a new all day event on 03/17/2016 with the default google calendar app on Android 6, I get 03/17/2016 01:00 because I'm using GMT+1. However I expect 03/17/2016 00:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several tries I found that all day events are not stored in UTC times or at least they are retrieved in a different way. Example:

All day event on 03/27/2016 0:00AM is actually treated as 03/27/2016 01:00 AM with GMT+1

So what you want to do is perform a query using milliseconds (UTC) and then
if the event is an all-day event check the time in this way:

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
long evStart =  cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Instances.BEGIN));
evStart -= tz.getOffset(evStart);
if (evStart < start)
//skip
```

In this way you can skip the event if it actually starts after start used in the query. I suspect that for an error the Instance query does return all normal events in UTC and, possibly at some outer level of the query, it mistakenly adjusts the all day event times to UTC even though they are already in UTC.